# Oracle ADF Table vertically Rows

Tags: oracle-adf, dbgrid

I was using Oracle forms 6i for long time, forms 6i have option to change tabular block to vertical. Is their any option in ADF table view to make vertical rows.
Example as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the pivot table component of ADF Faces for such a behavior.
https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=dvt%3ApivotTable

Or you can use an f:iterator component to layout this type of page:
https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=af%3Aiterator